# Accessing Nested Dictionaries through User Input - Student Data

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

In the query below, I am looking for output after getting the max value.

Input: `2539`
Output: `Mark:35`

```py
student_data = { '2539': { 'James': 30, 'Mark': 35, 'Jack':32}, '8214': { 'Michelle': 32,'Mark': 40,'Jack':32 }, '7411': { 'Travis': 28, 'Mark': 45,'Jack':32 } }


y=int(input("Enter ID":)


for id,v in student_data.items():       
    if y==v:

    max_student = max(v, key=v.get)   

    print(f'{id}:{max_student}:{v[max_student]}')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
student_data = { 2539: { 'James': 30, 'Mark': 35 }, 8214: { 'Michelle': 32,'Mark': 40 }, 7411: { 'Travis': 28, 'Mark': 45 } }

y = int(input('Enter ID:'))
for id,v in student_data.items():
    if y==id:
        max_student = max(v,key=v.get)
        print(f'{id}:{max_student}:{v[max_student]}') 
    else:
        continue
```

y couldn't be equal to v. You did a very small mistake of y==v instead of y==id.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this without using for loop you can check `y` is in `student_data`. If `y` exists find max student.

```
from statistics import median
student_data = { '2539': { 'James': 30, 'Mark': 35, 'Jack':32}, '8214': { 'Michelle': 32,'Mark': 40,'Jack':32 }, '7411': { 'Travis': 28, 'Mark': 45,'Jack':32 } }
y = input("Enter ID: ")

if y in student_data:
    max_student = max(student_data[y], key=student_data[y].get)   
    print(f'{max_student}:{student_data[y][max_student]}') 
    print(median(student_data[y].values()))
else:
    print('Id not found')
```

**Output:**

```
Enter ID: 2539
Mark:35
32
```

Comment: Hi Can u see that I have changed the primary ID key into strings in dictionary...its not integer … can you pls revert now

Comment: Actually I am also looking for median for the same dictionary such that the output will be like median value each dictionary … if I input 2539 output: 32.5

Comment: actually this is mean which you have wrote.... I need median the middle value from dictionary

Comment: Actually in this dictionary there is only 2 subkeys so here we mean and median could be same... but If I changed it to 3 subkeys then pls tell me the median … I appreciate your effort... you can see the change in dictionary

Comment: check now and will be waiting for your effort

Answer (score 0):

You don't need loop here,

```
student_data = { '2539': { 'James': 30, 'Mark': 35 }, '8214': { 'Michelle': 32,'Mark': 40 }, '7411': { 'Travis': 28, 'Mark': 45 } }

y=input("Enter ID:") # convert to int if dictionary keys are int

student_max = max(student_data[y], key=student_data[y].get)   

print(f'{student_max}: {student_data[y][student_max]}')
```

You get

```
Mark: 35
```